# Special delimiter when use read.csv()

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

I have a lot of .csv file that use "|" as delimiter:

> 1492624841097281|"19026960706021"|"3112642370"|"50000"|"0"|"VND"|""|""|"50000

I tried to read them like following

```
read.csv("a.csv",head=T, sep="|")
```

and

```
read.csv("a.csv",head=T, sep="\|")
```

I expect the columns will be separated but it didn't work. Please help me! Thanks a lot.

Comment: "it didn't work". Care to elaborate? What is the current output? What is the expected output? Is there any output at all? Is an exception thrown? Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry for making it messy, I edited the question already, thanks!

Comment: final `"` is missing from your sample. Try `read.table( "my.csv", sep = "|" )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `quote=""` in `read.csv("a.csv",head=T, sep="|")`

```
read.csv("a.csv",head=F, sep="|",quote="") # if the line is meant to be values
             V1                 V2             V3        V4    V5      V6   V7   V8       V9
1 "1492624841097281 ""19026960706021"" ""3112642370"" ""50000"" ""0"" ""VND"" """" """" ""50000"

read.csv("a.csv",head=T, sep="|",quote="") # if the line is meant to be the title
[1] X.1492624841097281  X..19026960706021.. X..3112642370..     X..50000..          X..0..             
[6] X..VND..            X....               X.....1             X..50000.          
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```